# Java 8 - Optional<CustomizedObject> get first element of the list within CustomizedObject

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am not sure how to do this

```
class Department {
    String deptName;
    List<Person> employees;
}

class Person {
    String personName;
}
```

The problem statement is to fetch the first name of the person working in a particular department. 
This department can be optional. So this is how my method looks -

```
String getFirstPerson(Optional<Department> department, String defaultName) {
// TODO: 
}
```

I know the traditional way of doing this but would like to see some Java 8 + lambda way to simplify this.
Still a newbie here - so please pardon if I am not using the correct format.

I also have a default name to use in case we dont find that value.

P.S. I know it is not best practice to send Optional as method parameter. This is not the actual code. I am just trying to simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `map` function on `Optional` to get the employees list and then use `stream` get the first name or return `defaultName`. Even incase if `Optional` is empty you will get the  `defaultName`

```
String getFirstPerson(Optional<Department> department, String defaultName) {

   return department.map(d->d.getEmployees().stream().map(Person::getPersonName).findFirst().orElse(defaultName)).orElse(defaultName));
}
```

If you have a chance of getting `null` on `getEmployees` you can use below approach

```
department.map(Department::getEmployees)
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .map(emp->emp.stream().map(Person::getPersonName).findFirst().orElse(defaultName)).orElse(defaultName)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplified way of doing that could be using `emptyList` for absent department or nullable `employees`:

```
String getFirstPerson(Optional<Department> department, String defaultName) {
    return department.map(Department::getEmployees)
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList()) // get rid of this ensuring non null List
            .stream()
            .map(Person::getPersonName)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(defaultName);
}
```

Comment: Note: This avoids the usage of `orElse(defaultName)` twice as in the marked answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in:

> ```
> department.map(Department::getEmployees)
>           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
>           .map(emp->emp.stream().map(Person::getPersonName).findFirst().orElse(defaultName)).orElse(defaultName)
> ```

we don't have to check non null since `.map(Department::getEmployees)` will return `Optional.empty()` if employees are null. See [Optional documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-).
Correct answer would be without redundant filter:

```
department.map(Department::getEmployees)
          .map(emp->emp.stream().map(Person::getPersonName).findFirst().orElse(defaultName)).orElse(defaultName)
```

Or alternatively:

```
department.map(Department::getEmployees)
          .map(List::stream)
          .map(Stream::findFirst)
          .flatMap(Functions.identity())
          .map(Person::getPersonName)
          .orElse(defaultName);
```